# How to zip multiple files through tcl script?

Tags: tcl

I'm trying to zip files from directory using Tcl but I'm able to zip only one file but rest of three files(a_2.txt,a_3.txt,a_4.txt) are not able to zip.I want zip all files at time.
On other hand I'm doing same thing from command prompt I'm able to execute successfully.

```
    directory 
    a_1.txt 
    a_2.txt 
    a_3.txt 
    a_4.txt


    #!/usr/local/bin/tclsh

    set dir /usr/test/abc/            
    array set g_config { ZIP /usr/bin/zip }

    proc zippingfile { files } {
    set out_files abc.10X
    set outdir /usr/test/out/ 

    exec $g_config(ZIP) $outdir$out_files $files

        }

    set filenames [exec ls $dir]
    cd $dir

    foreach line $filenames {
    append files "$line "
# the value of files should be a_1.txt a_2.txt a_3.txt a_4.txt
        }       

    zippingfile $files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array set g_config { ZIP /usr/bin/zip }

proc zippingfile { files } {
    global g_config
    set out_files abc.10X
    set outdir /usr/test/out
    exec $g_config(ZIP) [file join $outdir $out_files] {*}$files
}

set dir /usr/test/abc/            
cd $dir
set files [glob *]
zippingfile $files
```

Notes:

- work on your indentation
- you need the `global` command to access global vars from a proc
- be aware of the difference between strings and lists

  - you need to pass individual file arguments to `zip`, not a single list or a single string.
- [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), use the Tcl builtin [`glob`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/glob.htm)

Comment: Don't use external tools for things which can be done by Tcl directly. As recommended by you: "don't parse the output of ls, but use glob." The same is true for: "don't use /usr/bin/zip", but use Tcl's vfs capabilities. In both cases, using something external destroys Tcl's platform independence.https://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/zip/mkzip.html